# My Faenza icon theme contains an icon for spotify, but I can't seem to change the icon

Tags: launcher, icons, .desktop, spotify

So, I installed spotify (on 14.04) using [this method](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/previews/). It created a spotify folder in /opt/. My faenza icon theme seems to work for almost all supported apps except for spotify. I tried changing the icons manually in the /opt/spotify/icons folder and that didn't work either.

The spotify executable's icon inside /usr/share/applications changed but whenever the app's icon appears in the launcher, it's still the original spotify logo. I even went to the root folder and tried searching for any other instances of the original logo, but couldn't find any.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies with the naming of the spotify icon. Faenza and other iconsets name their Spotify icons `spotify` while the Spotify launcher expects an icon named `spotify-client`.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Edit `/opt/spotify/spotify-client/spotify.desktop` and replace `Icon=spotify-client` with `Icon=spotify`.

   The problem with this method is that your changes will be reverted next time Spotify is updated.
2. Modify your icon theme to include a `spotify-client` icon by creating a new symlink to `spotify.svg`:

   ```
    sudo ln -s '/usr/share/icons/Faenza/apps/scalable/spotify.svg' '/usr/share/icons/Faenza/apps/scalable/spotify-client.svg'
   ```

   Again, if you happen to update your Faenza theme you might lose these changes.

To preserve the changes to your icon theme you could copy `/usr/share/icons/Faenza` to `$HOME/.local/share/icons`.

Comment: Creating a symlink seemed to work! I had a few other minor issues with the icon after that, but those were easy to handle. Thanks a lot.